# Main Class is never being called

Tags: java, android

I had my project in a project named "NavigationDrawer" and realised that considering this was an app that had more than a Nav Drawer in it that it should be changed and renamed to something relevant.

I tried to import the project but it kept saying that there were no source files found, so I started to do it the old fashioned way (copying and pasting everything over making sure that I changed package names etc). But now when I try to run the program its saying that it cant find the MainActivity method. It keeps saying "Class 'MainActivity' is never used" and without it, my program wont run obviously.

I'm at my wits end here guys haha, I know its likely that I haven't edited one of the files or something but if you could point me in the right direction that would be great.

My code:

```
package com.example.ColeraineTown;

imports....

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private DrawerLayout DrawerLayout;
private ListView DrawerList;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle DrawerToggle;

private CharSequence DrawerTitle;
private CharSequence Title;
private String[] pageArray;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Title = DrawerTitle = getTitle();
    pageArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.pageArray);
    DrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    DrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
    DrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
    // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener
    DrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.drawer_list_item, pageArray));
    DrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

    // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
    // between the sliding drawer and the action bar app icon
    DrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,                  /* host Activity */
            DrawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
            R.drawable.ic_drawer,  /* nav drawer image to replace standard image in action bar */
            R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
            R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
    ) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(Title);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(DrawerTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };
    DrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(DrawerToggle);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        selectItem(0);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

/* Called whenever we call invalidateOptionsMenu() */
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view
    boolean drawerOpen = DrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(DrawerList);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_websearch).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
    // ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.
    if (DrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    // Handle action buttons
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_websearch:
            // create intent to perform web search for this planet
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
            intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, getActionBar().getTitle());
            // catch event that there's no activity to handle intent
            if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.app_not_available, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

/* The click listener for ListView in the navigation drawer */
private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        selectItem(position);
    }
}

private void selectItem(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = new PageFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(PageFragment.ARG_PAGE_NUMBER, position);
    fragment.setArguments(args);



    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

    // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
    DrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    setTitle(pageArray[position]);
    DrawerLayout.closeDrawer(DrawerList);
}

@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    Title = title;
    getActionBar().setTitle(Title);
}

/**
 * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
 * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
 */

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    DrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
    DrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

/**
 * Fragment that appears in the "content_frame", shows a planet
 */
public static class PageFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String ARG_PAGE_NUMBER = "page_number";

    public PageFragment() {
        // Empty constructor required for fragment subclasses
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_planet, container, false);
        int pgNum = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PAGE_NUMBER);
        String page = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.pageArray)[pgNum];

        int imageId = getResources().getIdentifier(page.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()),
                "drawable", getActivity().getPackageName());
        ((ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.image)).setImageResource(imageId);
        getActivity().setTitle(page);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: then check the manifest if you declared the activity as a launcher

Comment: Have you considered visiting developer.android.com which walks you through each step?  It will be quicker for you in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare it in the Android Manifest for that project.

```
<activity android:name="com.example.ColeraineTown.MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

[More docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html)